# What type of light fixture is this?

Tags: recessed-lighting

I just moved in recently and this light is in the ceiling of our closet. It's mostly burned out and I need to replace it. I have never seen a light fixture like this before.

[image: Light fixture]

The 2nd picture shows the plastic covering removed (removed 4 screws in corners).

[image: With removed cover]

It also apparently got so hot at one point that it melted the light cover.

[image: Melted Cover]

What do I need to look at for a replacement?

Comment: You don't specify, but be aware that (if you're in the US, at least) that you're not allowed to do electrical work in a rental. You can replace a light _bulb_, but not a light _fixture_. The landlord can't either, unless he happens to also be a licensed electrician. If you own the place, then carry on...

Comment: Thanks, I am the house owner now.

Answer (score 1):

That is a ceiling mount fixture with an LED circle for the lumination.

It is wired and replaced as is any other light fixture.  It is unusual for LEDs to get very hot.  It's good that you are replacing it.

You can replace it with any ceiling fixture you choose.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to remove more screws, I couldn't get the thing out.

Comment: Loosen the screw in the keyhole slot and twist the fixture (with the breaker off!). If it doesn't twist, it might be stuck by paint, so cut around the perimeter.